# Using AppleScript to delete select files in a folder?

Tags: macos, applescript

I have duplicate photos in a folder. (Thousands of them.) Their names are all Xxxxx (1).jpg. I'd like to automate their deletion but haven't hit on the correct syntax. I've been trying variants on the below and getting a variety of errors. Thanks very much for any suggestions!

```
tell application "Finder"

    delete (every item of folder {macintosh hd / users / mike / documents / OneDrive / Pictures} whose name contains "(1)")

end tell
```

For example, the error from the above was...

> Expected “,” or “}” but found identifier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you're getting `Expected “,” or “}” but found identifier.` is because you have a malformed `list` for the *path*. You cannot define the path like `{macintosh hd / users / mike / documents / OneDrive / Pictures}`.

Use the following instead:

```
tell application "Finder"
    delete (every item of folder "Macintosh HD:Users:mike:Documents:OneDrive:Pictures" whose name contains "(1)")
end tell
```

---

Depending on how may files there are to delete, Finder can have trouble running this AppleScript script, from taking far too much time and or the process stalling without recovery, to then require a Force Quit.

Personally, I would not use AppleScript and instead just use Terminal, and change directory to the one containing all the files and use `rm *\(1\)*` to delete all files containing `(1)`. **However use the `rm` command with great care because all deleted files are final!**

Comment: Unfortunately that causes my Finder to crash: "Finder got an error: AppleEvent timed out." number -1712" and then beach ball, Force Quit. Is there a different take on it? At a guess there are 6 GB of duplicates. Thanks again!

Comment: @Mikeca, I would not use AppleScript and instead just use Terminal, and change directory to the one containing all the files and use `rm *\(1\)*` to delete all files containing `(1)`. **However use the `rm` command with great care because all deleted files are final!**